# Getting Geopoint Data from Database Using Flutter Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I am implementing a project in Flutter firebase. In the application, it sends the locations of the places traveled by the user while the user is moving to the firestore database. I also want to get these locations from the database again, but I can't get the geopoints codes. I came across an input called "Instance of 'Geopoints' ". What I want is to get longtitude and latitude as coordinates in the input section that says "Instance of 'Geopoints'". For example (52.2165157N, 6.94378199E)

The piece of code we retrieved from the database:

```
getData() async {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Test')
    .where(('Liste'), arrayContains: "kosum1")
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  value.docs.forEach((result) {
     print(result.data().values.toString());
  });
});}
```

The piece of code we recorded in the database:

```
dataBaseSave() async {
final User user = auth.currentUser;
await _geolocator
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(
        latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').add({
      'Liste': FieldValue.arrayUnion([nb1, kosuadi, user.uid, point.data])
    });
    nb1++;
  });
});}
```

The output I get when I run it this way:
[image]

This is my database:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your screenshots, each document within your "Test" collection contains an array. At position 0 you have a number, at position 1 and 2 a String, and at position 3 an object. This object contains a geohash and a geopoint. The most important part of your code is:

```
result.data()
```

Which returns a Map. So when using the following line of code:

```
print(result.data().values.toString());
```

You are only printing the String representation of the Map. To be able to get the value of the geopoint property, you have to iterate through the Map and get the element (object) from the third position, which in terms is also a Map. Iterate again, and get the second element as a GeoPoint object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand a bit of what I'm going to try to do, but can you elaborate a bit more in your answer?

Comment: What exactly would you like to elaborate more?

Comment: My result.data() type is like this "QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>". But there is no option like result.data().geopoint. I still haven't figured out how to retrieve geopoint coordinates in firestore using result.data().

Comment: There is no result.data().geopoint because the geopoint is two-level deep, is inside the third object in the array. That's why I said to iterate twice.

Comment: I changed the query while saving it to the database and this is how I did it. I posted it as a new comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What you need to do iterate that Map object and get the data out of there. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to dig a little more into the data to get the information back. `result` is going to be an array that holds strings (index 0-2) and an object. That object looks like it has an instance of your GeoPoint. When you access that Geopoint you should be able to do `myGeopoint.latitude` and `myGeopoint.longitude` to get the two points. This is not exact, but it should look something like `result.data().values[3].geopoint.longitude` and same for longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query while saving it to the database and this is how I did it. So how should I do the get query from the database while in this state?

```
dataBaseSave() async {
final User user = auth.currentUser;
await _geolocator
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(
        latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Test').add({
      'Liste': FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          [nb1, kosuadi, user.uid, position.latitude, position.longitude])//I changed this place
    });
    nb1++;
  });
});}
```

And new database datas:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cast like below,

```
GeoPoint gpoint = result.data().values[3] as GeoPoint;
print(gpoint.latitude);
print(gpoint.longitude);
```